# Changing the display brightness depending on the lighting

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

It is necessary on the basis of the data received from the light sensor to change the display brightness, please help.

```
public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent s)
{
     if (s.Sensor.Type == SensorType.Light)
     {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Brightness" + s.Values[0]);
     }        
}
```

Comment: Are you just doing this for android or in XF?

Comment: So just under android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change brightness with the WindowManager

```
Window.Attributes.ScreenBrightness = 0.0

    //     value of less than 0, the default, means to use the preferred screen brightness.
    //     0 to 1 adjusts the brightness from dark to full bright.
    //     [Android Documentation]
```

Comment: if (s.Sensor.Type == SensorType.Light)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Light sensor" + s.Values[0]);
                Window.Attributes.ScreenBrightness = s.Values[0];

            }

Comment: Reading here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/761/changing-screen-brightness you may have to copy the attributes, change the brightness and set it

Comment: Just to be clear, this does not change the "system display" brightness (which is not permitted), it changes the brightness of *your* app's window